# What if I DROP and ACCEPT the same IP address in iptables? What will take precedence?

Tags: iptables, firewall

I am playing around iptables to filter the packets coming and going. What will be the result of following rules?

```
iptables -A INPUT -s 192.168.1.0/24 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -s 192.168.1.0/24 -j DROP
```

Comment: Already answered here http://askubuntu.com/questions/423630/iptables-order-of-rules-do-i-understand-it-right

Comment: You might want to check out Mignis for [declarative iptables configuration](https://secgroup.dais.unive.it/wp-content/uploads/2010/09/firewall-corso.pdf), because sometimes writing rules in the correct order is tricky.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Iptables (and most firewall software) operates on a concept of first match wins, so if the rules are in the order posted above, the ACCEPT will match first and will be the effective policy applied to the packet.

Comment: Because of this behavior, the most-specific (longest CIDR /net suffix) should always come before more general rules that might also match.  For instance, if there's another rule for 192.168.0.0/16, it has to follow this, or it will make the specific rule irrelevant.

Answer (score 1):

When the incoming connection hits your firewall, it's going to go down the line in your configuration file. Therefore it will ACCEPT all traffic from 192.168.1.0/24.